# Older to newer version conversion

Tags: python

I started working with python with version 3.4 and then I used qt create to make some ui files, but then when I had to use tensorflow, I upgraded my python and everything to python 3.6. Now after a while when I had to use those qt ui files again, they seem to read the older version and hence show an error.

[image]

Comment: According to this `C:\Python34` doesn't exist on your computer. Has nothing to do with your code

Comment: Do not post images of text output please. On my screen this is unreadable. It can also not be found by searching for those with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have to go through your files that you created and change any references to C:\Python34\python that you hardcoded. Alternatively, if Python 3.4 is completely uninstalled from your system and you don't want to go through the hassle of changing all of your hard links, you could just enter this command into your terminal:

```
mklink /J C:\Python34 C:\Python36
```

This will create a symbolic link where your old Python34 directory was and should fix your issue (again though, recommend that you take the time to change any hardcoded references instead of this).